# How do I add Function to my Check Box's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I am currently adding functionality to my game and I have a 2 options for the user

They can disable flash and text

I currently have 2 check boxes the user must check what functions they want before starting the game

I want to add an onclick function, that if the user selects the check button that function will be in the game when they run it and if they dont it wont

For example if the user wants the flashes they check the box etc

To get a better understanding play the fiddle to see what I mean

Heres is a link to the full game in a fiddle(with sound already disabled due to it not being supported in fiddle) Also make sure you extend it to see all of the game and the side bar

http://jsfiddle.net/uusL7hch/17/

```js
var game = { //game object
    level: 1, //current level
    turn: 0, //current turn
    difficulty: 1, // user difficulty
    score: 0, //current score
    active: false, //whether a turn is active or not
    handler: false, // whether the click and sound handlers are active
    shape: '.shape', // cached string for the pad class
    genSequence: [], //array containing the generated/randomized pads
    plaSequence: [], //array containing the users pad selections
    colors: ['green', 'red', 'purple', 'blue'],
    init: function () { //initialises the game
        if (this.handler === false) { //checks to see if handlers are already active
            this.initPadHandler(); //if not activate them
        }
        this.newGame(); //reset the game defaults
    },

    initPadHandler: function () {
        that = this;
        $('.pad').on('mouseup', function () {
            if (that.active === true) {
                var pad = parseInt($(this).data('pad'), 10);
                that.flash($(this), 1, 300, pad);
                that.logPlayerSequence(pad);
            }
        });
        this.handler = true;
    },

    newGame: function () { //resets the game and generates a starts a new level
        this.level = 1;
        this.score = 0;
        this.newLevel();
        this.displayLevel();
        this.displayScore();

        //initialize timer to 10 seconds (10.0)
        this.timer = 10;
    },

    newLevel: function () {
        this.genSequence.length = 0;
        this.plaSequence.length = 0;
        this.pos = 0;
        this.turn = 0;
        this.active = true;

        this.randomizePad(this.level); //randomize pad with the correct amount of numbers for this level
        this.displaySequence(); //show the user the sequence
    },

    flash: function (element, times, speed, pad) { //function to make the pads appear to flash
        var that = this; //cache this

        if (times > 0) { //make sure we are supposed to flash
            that.playSound(pad); //play the corresponding pad sound
            element.stop().animate({
                opacity: '1'
            }, { //animate the element to appear to flash
                duration: 50,
                complete: function () {
                    element.stop().animate({
                        opacity: '0.6'
                    }, 200);
                }
            }); //end animation
        }

        if (times > 0) { //call the flash function again until done the correct amount of times 
            setTimeout(function () {
                that.flash(element, times, speed, pad);
            }, speed);
            times -= 1; //times - 1 for each time it's called
        }
    },
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    playSound: function (clip) { //plays the sound that corresponds to the pad chosen
        return; //not supported in jsfiddle
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        var sound = $('.sound' + clip)[0];
        console.log(sound);
        console.log($('.sound' + clip));
        sound.currentTime = 0; //resets audio position to the start of the clip
        sound.play(); //play the sound
    },

    randomizePad: function (passes) { //generate random numbers and push them to the generated number array iterations determined by current level
        for (i = 0; i < passes; i++) {
            this.genSequence.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1);
        }
    },

    logPlayerSequence: function (pad) { //log the player selected pad to user array and call the checker function
        this.plaSequence.push(pad);
        this.checkSequence(pad);
    },

    checkSequence: function (pad) { //checker function to test if the pad the user pressed was next in the sequence
        that = this;

        if (pad !== this.genSequence[this.turn]) { //if not correct 
            this.incorrectSequence();
        } else { //if correct
            this.keepScore(); //update the score
            this.turn++; //incrememnt the turn
        }

        if (this.turn === this.genSequence.length) { //if completed the whole sequence
            this.level++; //increment level, display it, disable the pads wait 1 second and then reset the game
            this.displayLevel();
            this.active = false;

            // Stop counting when sequence is correct to avoid time running out before starting next level
            clearInterval(this.timerInterval);

            //Add 5.0 seconds each 5th level
            this.timer = 10 + 5 * Math.floor(this.level / 5);

            //Update timerdisplay to show fulltime while displaying next level sequence
            $(".Timer p").html(this.timer);

            setTimeout(function () {
                that.newLevel();
            }, 1000);
        }
    },

    // Countdown and update timer, call incorrectsequence when time's up
    countDown: function () {
        this.timer -= 0.1;
        $(".Timer p").html(this.timer.toFixed(1)); // Display 9.0 instad of 9
        if (this.timer < 0.1) {
            this.incorrectSequence();
        }
    },

    displaySequence: function () { //display the generated sequence to the user
        var that = this;
        var timerCount = 0;

        $.each(this.genSequence, function (index, val) { //iterate over each value in the generated array
            timerCount = index;
            setTimeout(function () {
                that.flash($(that.shape + val), 1, 300, val);
                $(".TextBox").children(":first").html('<b>'+that.colors[val-1]+'</b>');
            }, 500 * index * that.difficulty); // multiply timeout by how many items in the array so that they play sequentially and multiply by the difficulty modifier
        });

        // Wait to start timer until full sequence is displayed
        setTimeout(function () {
            that.timerInterval = setInterval(function () {
                that.countDown()
            }, 100)
        setTimeout(function(){$(".TextBox").children(":first").html('');}, 500);
        }, 500 * timerCount * that.difficulty);
    },

    displayLevel: function () { //just display the current level on screen
        $('.level h2').text('Level: ' + this.level);
    },

    displayScore: function () { //display current score on screen
        $('.score h2').text('Score: ' + this.score);
    },

    keepScore: function () { //keep the score
        var multiplier = 0;
        switch (this.difficulty) //choose points modifier based on difficulty
        {
            case '2':
                multiplier = 1;
                break;
            case '1':
                multiplier = 2;
                break;
            case '0.5':
                multiplier = 3;
                break;
            case '0.25':
                multiplier = 4;
                break;
        }

        this.score += (1 * multiplier); //work out the score

        this.displayScore(); //display score on screen
    },

    incorrectSequence: function () { //if user makes a mistake

        //Stop counting down timer and display start message
        clearInterval(this.timerInterval);
        $(".Timer p").html("Get Ready your time starts when you click start");

        var corPad = this.genSequence[this.turn], //cache the pad number that should have been pressed

            that = this;
        this.active = false;
        this.displayLevel();
        this.displayScore();

        setTimeout(function () { //flash the pad 4 times that should have been pressed
            that.flash($(that.shape + corPad), 4, 300, corPad);
        }, 500);
        
        $(".TextBox").children(":first").html("<b>the good answer was "+that.colors[corPad-1]+"</b>");
        
        $('.start').show(); //enable the start button again and allow difficulty selection again
        $('.difficulty').show();
    }
};
$(document).ready(function () { //document ready
    $('.start').on('mouseup', function () { //initialise a game when the start button is clicked
        $(this).hide();
        game.difficulty = $('input[name=difficulty]:checked').val();
        $('.difficulty').hide();
        game.init();
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
}

.wrapper2 {
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    width: 650px;
    height: 700px;
    margin-left:25%;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;border-radius: 15px;border: 5px groove #8E2B2B; padding-left: 0.5em;
}

.wrapper3{
    position: relative;
    float:right;
    width: 300px;
    height: 700px;
    margin-right:1%;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;border-radius: 15px;border: 5px groove #8E2B2B; padding: 0.5em;
}

.Timer{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    margin-top:235px;
    margin-left:177px;
    border:5px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color:black;
    text-align:center;
}

.TextBox{
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
    margin-top:30px;
    margin-left:177px;
    border:5px solid white;
    background-color:black;
    text-align:center;
}

.pad {
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 10px;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.shape1 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.shape2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 2.5px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.shape3 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 78%;
    right: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    margin-right: -50px;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: purple;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.shape4 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 50%;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.level, .score {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.sButton {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: black;
    border: 3pt ridge Black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.start {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="wrapper2">
        <div class="pad shape1" data-pad="1">
            <audio preload="auto" class="sound1">
                <source src="Media/mp3/sounds_01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
                <source src="Media/ogg/sounds_01.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
            </audio>
        </div>
        <div class="pad shape2" data-pad="2">
            <audio preload="auto" class="sound2">
                <source src="Media/mp3/sounds_02.mp3"  type="audio/mpeg"/>
                <source src="Media/ogg/sounds_02.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
            </audio>
        </div>
        <div class="Timer">
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <p><b>Get Ready your time starts when you click start</b></P>
        </div>            
        <div class="TextBox">
            <p><b>Get Ready and click the buttons who's name appear here</b></P>
        </div>
        <div class="pad shape3" data-pad="3">
            <audio preload="auto" class="sound3">
                <source src="Media/mp3/sounds_03.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
                <source src="Media/ogg/sounds_03.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
            </audio>
        </div>
        <div class="pad shape4" data-pad="4">
            <audio preload="auto" class="sound4">
                <source src="Media/mp3/sounds_04.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"/>
                <source src="Media/ogg/sounds_04.ogg" type="audio/ogg"/>
            </audio>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper3">
        <div class="level">
            <h2>Level: 1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="score">
            <h2>Score: 0</h2>
        </div>
        
        <ul class="difficulty">
            <li>
                <input type="radio" class="difOpt" name="difficulty" value="2">Easy
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" class="difOpt" name="difficulty" value="1" checked>Normal
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" class="difOpt" name="difficulty" value="0.5">Hard
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="radio" class="difOpt" name="difficulty" value="0.25">Insane
            </li>
        </ul>
        <p>Do You want Flashes ? </p>
        <input type="checkbox"value="No"style="color: Black;">Yes

        <p>Do You want Text ? </p>
        <input type="checkbox"value="No"style="color: Black;">Yes
        <br />
        <div class="sButton">
            <button class="start">START</button>
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

Any help would be great

Comment: why use radio buttons and not checkboxes? in your situation you would need two radios, one for on and another for off

Comment: @LoganMurphy yeah that makes more sense now that i think about I have changed the above html and added check instead of radio. thanks now can u help with a full answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter your sound checkbox by adding an id to make it easier to select with jQuery

```
<input type="checkbox"value="No"style="color: Black;" id="sound">
```

You need to alter you `playSound` function to check if sounds should be played or not by seeing if the sound checkbox is checked

```
...
playSound: function (clip) { //plays the sound that corresponds to the pad chosen
    if($("#sound").is(":checked")) {
        var sound = $('.sound' + clip)[0];
        console.log(sound);
        console.log($('.sound' + clip));
        if(sound.duration) {
            sound.currentTime = 0; //resets audio position to the start of the clip
            sound.play(); //play the sound
        }
    }
}
...
```

Here is the resulting fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uusL7hch/16/

Comment: well sound is already disable because it cant be supported by fiddle, so i cant tell if anything is happening,and second when i select the checkbox it breaks the rest of the game as in none of the functions work ?

Comment: look at the log...your console logs and errors show up only when sound is enabled

Comment: yes i can see that but now when the sound checkbox is click all the other functions dont work including text and flash

Comment: the solution only works when sound sources are available...i updated the fiddle to include the return statement so that the program doesnt crash when accessing invalid sound sources

Comment: Thanks was now able to use this to get the other two working thanks alot mate